# Excel VBA Replace

Tags: vba, excel

`Replace(Range("D3").Value,"aaaaaa",Range("C"&c))`

Is the above code line correct?

I want to replace the `aaaaaa` text in a string in the Cell `D3` with a text from the text in `column C` and the cell location is controlled by a variable `c` which will be incremented by 1 after a condition is met.
I want to make this a macro.

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried the code?  What did you expect to occur?

Comment: Well range("C" & c) you are missing the .Value

Answer (score 1):

Just :

```
Sheets("your sheet").Range("D3").text = Sheets("your sheet").Range("C"& c).text
```

Comment: Better to use `Value` - `Text` will use whatever is displayed.  As an example:  Enter the date in cell D3 and make the column too narrow to display it all - `....Range("D3").Text` will return `########`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook In addition to that, `.Text` is a **read-only** property of the Excel `Range` object.